# Get value through AJAX an display it on element CodeIgniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

first of all let me clarify that i am a totally begginer on AJAX and CodeIgniter.

I am reading this article to start and I think I understand some:

http://www.amitavroy.com/justread/content/articles/getting-ajax-data-using-views-codeigniter

What I need to do, is to update a `Input Field` in a form when changing the `select` html element.

```
<select class="select" name="formulario">
  <?php
  foreach($listaForms as $form) {
    echo "<option value={$form}>{$form}</option>";
  }
  ?>
</select>
```

I know how to do this:

1) With jquery, listen to `change()`.
2) Make the ajax function with POST.
3) Make the public function to retrieve data.

Well, the problem goes here...

In the tutorial i'm reading, the guy gets HTML response.

I would only need one value, or many values. In this particular case I need only one value, that is the last printed number (stored in a text file).

The question is, how can I identify the value I need, suppose the response is:

```
LastPrintedNumber=>23
OtherValue=>20
```

How can I do with Javascript to correcly identify the value I need in the response and then change it?

I suppose that once I identify and get the value, I will only need to change the `value` of the Input Text field.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server's response should be in JSON format. Use PHP's json_encode function. Your PHP  (server-side) code should be something like this:

```
// if it's a json request
if(!empty($_POST['data']) && 'ajax' == $_POST['data'])
{
    $res = array('LastPrintedNumber' => 23, 'OtherValue' => 20);
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($res);
    exit; // no need to render the template
}
```

Modify your jQuery code so that it can handle/parse a JSON response:

```
  $(function(){
    $('#formulario').change(function() {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/migup',
        data: {'data' : 'ajax', 'selectedValue' : $(this).val()},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(val) {
          console.log('LastPrintedNumber: ' + val.LastPrintedNumber);
          alert('OtherValue:' + val.OtherValue);
        }        
      });
    });
  });
```

Hope that helps. Cheers!

Comment: Excelent! Even simpler than I thought, everything is resolved in the .ajax function. Thanks!